# Sending large files (images) over internet using a C server

Tags: c, image, web-services, http, web

I am creating a simple webserver in C using sockets, it listens on port 10001; so far it works and I can load all images fine in my browser when I use `http://127.0.0.1:10001/`. But when I try to access it on the website all the images larger than 4kb don't get displayed, and when I open them individually it only shows about 1/3th of the image.

I have a nameserver redirect traffic to my router at port 80, which then in turn forwards it to port 10001 on my local machine.

The files get send like this (in this case a jpeg image):

```
FILE *fp;
char *buf, header[1024];
int fsize, hsize, nbytes;
struct tm *itime;
time_t rawtime;

fp = fopen(file, "r");

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
fsize = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp);

time(&rawtime);
itime = localtime(&rawtime);

hsize = sprintf(header, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
                        "Server: iserv\r\n"
                        "Date: %s"
                        "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
                        "Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n"
                        "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n"
                        "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n", asctime(itime), fsize);

write(fd, header, hsize);

buf = (char*)malloc(CHUNK_SIZE);
while((nbytes = fread(buf, sizeof(char), CHUNK_SIZE, fp)) > 0)
    write(fd, buf, nbytes);

free(buf);
```

Why does this problem occur, and how can I solve it?

Comment: ftell documentation says that the return value is only meaningful to fseek for restoring the position when using text mode (versus binary mode).  Try opening the file in binary mode "rb".  (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/)

Comment: You don't show how you open `fd`. Is it in non-blocking mode? You appear not to be checking the return value of the `write()` to `fd`, so how do you know everything is being written?

Comment: @abligh I know everything is being written because when I test the exact same thing on localhost it works, all the images get loaded.

Comment: @1337 I understand this, but it works on localhost, so the fseek can't change on that situation right?

Comment: @ThomasVersteeg that makes me think it is *more* likely to be blocking, which is far more likely to take place on a remote host than localhost. All you need to do is try capturing the return value of `write()`.

Comment: The machines the packet traverses on the internet at large may enforce the header more strictly than your local setup.  Try printing fsize in a debug message or sniffing the outgoing packet to see if the value under content-length is as expected.

Comment: @abligh I tested it and indeed you were right, all I had to do was set the socket to blocking using `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) & ~O_NONBLOCK);`, if you create an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `write()` is not writing the whole data out because your socket is set to non-blocking and you are not checking the amount written. The simplest fix is to clear `O_NONBLOCK` with `fcntl(fd, FSET_FL ...)`.